# control dialogbox of an external application

Tags: c#, dialog

I'm writing a program in C# to automate another application. I use user32 api. When the external application needs user input, my C# program fills the boxes and presses the buttons. When a new window comes up, I can find it and it's controls using findwindow() and findwindowex() function but when this dialog comes up (in the picture) I cannot find the controls in it(the buttons). Even UI Spy cannot show them. I tried to send key events to this window but nothing happened. Can you give me some tips how to go on?

[image]

Comment: If you try Spy++ they seem to be visible in that.